# pointer-events none on an outer div, but not on an inner iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

i need a div to have a `pointer-events:none` on a div but not on a div inside an iframe that is inside that div.

basically i `.contentWindow.document.write` the div into the iframe, and then
i need that specific inner div to react to mouse events even thought the div containing the iframe has a `pointer-events:none`

`pointer-events:auto` wont work because it still inherits the `none` and all the other options are "svg only".

I only need this to work in chrome!

seems to say that "auto" works here, but it doesnt for me:http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on what you are targeting.

### [Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ945/)

Try setting the pointer-events of your iframe to `auto`.

```
iframe{
    pointer-events: auto; /*You can add !important too if necessary*/
}
```

Remember that the contents of an iframe are their own document and do not inherit CSS from the parent, so your iframe is what is not clickable, rather than the div inside it.